# Qt 5 with SQLite: bindValue() results in "Parameter count mismatch" error

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5, qtsql, qsqlquery

I'm doing a simple parameterized query with Qt 5.3.1 (64-bit) on Windows 7 using the SQLite driver. When I use `bindValue()` to set the value of the single parameter of my query, I systematically get the dreaded "Parameter count mismatch" error. Everything works fine when I use `addBindValue()`. Note that the code with `bindValue()` works fine with Qt 4.8.5 (64-bit).

Here is the full code (`main.cpp`):

```
#include <QtSql>

int main(int, char* [])
{
    auto db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("db.sqlite");
    db.open();

    {
        QSqlQuery query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hashes (filepath TEXT, modified INTEGER, hash TEXT)", db);
        query.exec();
    }

    QSqlQuery query("SELECT modified FROM hashes WHERE filepath = :fp", db);
    query.bindValue(":fp", "test.jpg");

    if (!query.exec())
        qDebug() << query.lastError();

    db.close();

    return 0;
}
```

QtCreator project file (`qtsqltest.pro`):

```
QT += core sql
TARGET = qtsqltest
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Program output on my machine:

```
QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")
```

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt QSqlQuery bindValue works with ? but not with :placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786003/qt-qsqlquery-bindvalue-works-with-but-not-with-placeholders)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found out that my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786003/qt-qsqlquery-bindvalue-works-with-but-not-with-placeholders) and that the [corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20786508/393756) is correct.

It turns out that query strings passed to the constructor of `QSqlQuery` are executed immediately, as per the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2).

It isn't clear why such queries are working fine with Qt 4.8.5, or why they do work with Qt 5.3.1 when using positional parameters (using `?` placeholders) while they fail with named parameters (using `:` placeholders).

Comment: I had a similar problem, but in my case what solved it was adding parenthesis in the query, so instead of `query.prepare( "INSERT INTO tablename (columnname) VALUES :placeholder" );` I had to do `query.prepare( "INSERT INTO tablename (columnname) VALUES (:placeholder)" );`

Comment: I had a similar problem (with a correct use of prepare), but mine mistake was a typo in sql query (I had "SELECT a, b, cFROM table" instead of "SELECT a, b, c FROM table")...Error message "Parameter count mismatch" was really misleading here...Might help someone, good luck!

Comment: I also had similar problem . But I was wrong at set datadase path

          

> db.setDatabaseName(path);

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the reputation to add a comment to the solution, so here, just to add yet another potential culprit: I was trying to bind a value to the column name and I got the `Parameter count mismatch` error, which seems to be the go-to error message no matter what the actual error is :)

It turns out this is simply an invalid approach to SQL, see [QSqlQuery with prepare and bindValue for column name Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902859/qsqlquery-with-prepare-and-bindvalue-for-column-name-sqlite).

So instead of

```
query.prepare("UPDATE connections SET (:columnName) = (:value) WHERE id = (:id)");
query.bindValue(":columnName", someColumnName);
query.bindValue(":value", someValue);
query.bindValue(":id", someId);
```

do this:

```
query.prepare(QString("UPDATE connections SET %1 = (:value) WHERE id = (:id)").arg(someColumnName));
query.bindValue(":value", someValue);
query.bindValue(":id", someId);
// etc.
```

This is not what the OP did but this thread is what came first during my search and it might save somebody else some time.

Comment: Thanks for this; same situation for me. Too bad it's not allowed, lol.