# QT select from mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm beginner in qt. I'm using qt5 in ubuntu.
I want to select some columns from a table in mysql database where one column(id) is equal to a variable in integer type. What should I do?
I wrote this code but I have error!

```
QSqlQuery query;
int k=10;
query.exec("select name,family from employees where id='"+k+"'");
while(query.next()){
    qDebug()<<query.value(0).toString();
    qDebug()<<query.value(1).toString();
}
```

And this is the error:

```
 invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
 query.exec("select name,family from employees where id='"+k+"'");
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is, what do you not understand?

Comment: Beacuse he probably doesnt understand it, and lazy apparently, thats why there is a place called SO ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Qt, but simple google search return :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15902962/4421474

So in your case it could be:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare(QString("select name,family from employees where id = :id"));
query.bindValue(":id", k);
query.exec();
```

By the way you have typo `"selecr` must be `"select`.